# Complaints about stray <head> tags

Tags: html

Both the W3C validator and my Firefox source browser are complaining about stay `<head>` tags. The page itself displays fine. Below part of the html code produced by my php scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<!--scripts/head.php-->
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012 Studiopatty
-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <title>Studio Patty: Kapster en Buikdanseres - Kapster</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Patty studiopatty dansschool buikdansschool kapster buikdansen buikdanstheater oervrouwen Rozenburg Voorne-putten">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css?20121212" type="text/css"/>
    <link class="cssfx" rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css?20121212" type="text/css"/>
    <link class="cssfx" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?20121212" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="scripts/cssfx.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/tattoo.ico">

</head>
<body>
<!--scripts/navigation.php-->
<div id="sidebar">
<a class="logo" href="index.php"></a>

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a class="nav" id="upper" title="Over mijn kapsalon" href="kapster.php">Kapster</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Algemeen" href="buikdanseres.php">Buikdanseres</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Mijn ervaring met buikdansen" href="over.php">Over Patty</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Informatie over lessen die ik geef" href="lessen.php">Lessen</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Het buikdantheater" href="buikdanstheater.php">Buikdanstheater</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Agenda" href="evenementen.php">Evenementen</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Videos van projecten, optredens en lessen" href="media.php">Beeld en geluid</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" title="Contact" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" id="down" title="Links naar andere webpagina's" href="links.php">Vrienden</a></li>
</ul>
<footer><p class="center footer"><a href="copyright.php">&copy Copyright 2012 - Patty Willemsen<br>
and others</a></p></footer>
</div><!--scripts/foto.php-->
<script>
var pic_array=new Array("foto/Patty.jpg", "foto/IMG_5635.jpg", "foto/DSCN0889.jpg", "foto/Buikdanslesgroep_073.JPG", "foto/385079_270974476272094_100000786300365_743607_1443696752_n.jpg", "foto/863234958_5_nK1e.jpg", "foto/374577_270974419605433_100000786300365_743605_1359936845_n.jpg");
var num_pics=7;
var current_pic=0;
var picTimer;

function timePictures()
{ picTimer=setTimeout("nextPicture()", 10000); }

function nextPicture()
{ current_pic++; if(current_pic>=num_pics) current_pic=0;
document.getElementById("NewPic").src=pic_array[current_pic]; }

</script>

<div class="slideshow">
<img id="NewPic" src="foto/Patty.jpg" alt="test" onload="timePictures();"/>
</div>

<div id="text">
<div class="banner"></div>

<!--content/kapster_text.php-->
<h2>Heren-en Dameskapster<br>"Patty"</h2>

<table class="nice" border="0">
<tr><th rowspan="3">Werktijden:</th><td class="middle">maandag </td><td>13.00 - 20.00 uur</td></tr>
<tr>                                                <td class="middle">dinsdag </td><td>09.30 - 16.30 uur</td></tr>
<tr>                                                <td class="middle">donderdag </td><td>09.30 - 16.30 uur</td></tr>
</table>

<p class="nice"><b>Behandeling op afspraak.</b> <br>
Elzenlaan 15 <br> 
3181 BG Rozenburg <br>
0181-213372 / 06-12896620 </p>

<p class="center">
Graag wil ik je uitnodigen voor prachtig haar
</p>
<div class="banner"></div>
</div> <!--div id="text"-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are those HTML comments with `<!--scripts/head.php-->` and `<!--scripts/navigation.php-->`? Are they PHP includes of some kind?

Comment: I tested this via http://validator.w3.org/check and I don't receive anything but two warnings that can be ignored.

Comment: Do you happen to have `<head>` elements in the _content_?

Comment: You need to give an example that actually gives the error when run through a validator.

Comment: I guess the problem is in _content_. No, I have no `<head>` tags in there. If I validate the complete page is barfs the errors, not when validating the snippit like I posted. Strange...

The HTML comments are for debugging purpose, so I know what piece of code is coming from which script in case of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the actual web page and the problem is a single invisible character just before the second comment before the `<head>` tag.

```
<!--scripts/head.php-->
 <!--
^
HERE IS AN INVALID CHARACTER

Copyright (c) 2012 Studiopatty
-->
```

The character causes the validator to think `<head>` has started implicitly and complain about the actual `<head>` tag.

Some editors let you add an invisible binding character if you press space with a modifier like ctrl or alt, which easily leads to situations like this.

Comment: I cleaned up any white spaces and newlines before and after the comments, but it did not change anything. I edited my post with the full code from the site, including this changes

Comment: Did you update the web page already? The character is still there. (It'd be best to delete and rewrite those lines completely.) You'll notice that again if you copy-paste the code from the updated question it validates correctly (except for 2 unrelated errors).

Comment: @Tim: the issue could be a Byte Order Mark, which is present in your pages. Configure your editor to not add those characters.

Comment: True, but if I copy-paste the same data into the validator it gives 11 errors. I am not working direclty on the site you'll find on google ;). The one I am editing is [here](http://test.studiopatty.nl)

Comment: That URL [validates without errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.studiopatty.nl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), so what's the problem?

Comment: @Arjan: I converted the scripts involved in the index.php to utf-8 without BOM just now, but it did not have effect. Is is sometting PHP could be producing?

**EDIT** I should have be more patient with checking, probably the caches where not flushed. removing the BOM was the solution